# appsetting.json modified but still return old values?

Tags: asp.net-core

I used the config in `Startup.cs` file (and in also in other).

```
app.UseCors(options =>
{
   options.WithOrigins(Configuration["AllowedCors"]).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

I publish my code (to deploy),
and sometimes, I have to changes my `appsettings.json`.
But, seem like it's still getting old value. And I always need to restart my app to getting new value work.

Does anyone have anny idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **reloadOnChange: true** in your startup file.

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Comment: Does that reloads appsettings values without stopping the deployment?

Comment: Yes, if you change the file, it reloads and no need to restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IOptionsSnapshot** instead of **IOptions** for inject settings in the constructor, after set **reloadOnChange: true** like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61793851/8730051).

```
private readonly BranchSettings _settings;

public Constructor(IOptionsSnapshot<BranchSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings?.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is what you are asking, but when you change appsettings.json on a already running deployment, to load new values you have to restart that deployment. 
EDIT: Seems like I was mistaken, Ali gave a simple solution without restarting the application.